# Отсортировать записи по параметрам

Tags: php, wordpress

Ломаю голову уже несколько дней. Может кто-нибудь подскажет как решить задачку.

Сайт написан на Wordpress. Есть 15 записей, выведенных на страницу. Каждой записи присвоен определенный параметр-ключевое слово. Когда пользователь заходит на сайт по определенному ключевому слову, нужно запись которая имеет этот параметр, ставить самой первой.

Это делается для того, чтобы пользователь не рылся по сайту, а сразу находил то что ищет. Как можно реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: order by keyword <> "параметр" - это в запросе, как такое сказать wordpress'у - не знаю

Comment: "Когда пользователь заходит на сайт по определенному ключевому слову," - это как?

Comment: Все возможные виды сортировок https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#orderby